# Grep next word after pattern match

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I'm trying to get grep/sed out the following output: *"name":"test_backup_1"* from the below response

```
{"backups":[{"name":"test_backup_1","status":"CORRUPTED","creationTime":"2019-11-08T15:03:49.460","id":"test_backup_1"}]}
```

I have been trying variations of the following `grep -Eo 'name:"\w+\"'` but no joy.

I'm not sure if it would be easier to achieve this using grep or sed?

The way I am running this is curling a response from the server and saving it to a local variable, then echo out the variable and pipe grep/sed

example of what I am running 
`echo ${view_backup} | grep -Eo '"name":"\w+\"'`

Comment: Have you considered parsing the JSON instead?

Comment: What would parsing the JSON do for me?

The above response is from a curl from a server and all I need to retrieve is the name

Comment: If `jq` is available, please try: `jq -r .backups[].name input.json` which yields `test_backup_1`.

Comment: The server this will be running on won't have `jq` installed on it

Comment: Then how about: `grep -Eo '"name":"[^"]+"' input.json`?

Comment: Hi @Sundeep expect output would be "name":"test_backup_1"

Comment: @tshiono, that returned <blank>

Comment: grep is a line-oriented tool, don't use it for parsing JSON. if jq isn't available, you still have python, perl, etc.

Comment: @user3292394 `echo '{"backups":[{"name":"test_backup_1","stat' | grep -Eo '"name":"[^"]+"'` does return `"name":"test_backup_1"` ... so probably you have some other issue unrelated to `grep` or may your `grep` version doesn't support some part of this command?

Comment: Hi @Sundeep, running the above command did return the expected output, but when I tried to echo out the local variable and run it, it returned a blank.

Comment: then try debugging it further.. for example, does this work? `a='{"backups":[{"name":"test_backup_1","stat'` followed by `echo "${a}" | grep -Eo '"name":"[^"]+"'` ... and so on..

Comment: Hi @Sundeep, I found, my error. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing @sundeep answer

`grep -Eo '"name":"[^"]+"'`

resulted in the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to transform the file to one line before grep

and pipe from your curl

```
echo `curl --silent https://someurl | tr -d '\n' | grep  -oP "(?<=name\":\")[^\"]+"`
```

will return

test_backup_1

If you want more variables you can chain the -oP grep like in this example where I get some data on a danish license plate (bt419329)

```
curl --silent https://www.tjekbil.dk/api/v2/nummerplade/bt41932 | grep -oP -m 1 "(?<=\"RegNr\":\")[^\"]+|(?<=\"MaerkeTypeNavn\":\")[^\"]+|(?<=\"MaksimumHastighed\":)[^,]+"| tr '\n' ' '
```

returns

BT41932 SKODA 218